# When Are Signals Handled?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, signals, interrupt

I read:

> Signals are handled only when **the receiving process** has returned
> from kernel mode to user mode.

But that doesn't make sense to me, **why**?

Theoretically, let's say process A is running and it sent a signal to process B, When process B starts running it might never run in kernel mode those never see the signal and handle it.

But, in real world signals are handled nearly instantly (At least from my own observations), How is this possible as I'm seeing a clear contradiction?

Comment: log the time when you send the signal and the time in the signal handler.

Comment: I, too have been confused by signal handling.  It seems to me that, if the target process is not running, the OS cannot 'immediately' deliver a signal and that must wait until the target enters the kernel for some other reason, unrelated to signals, eg. a syscall or I/O/timer interrupt.  That would seem to introduce latency, but that may be unavoidable.

Comment: I wonder if it is possibke to request that the target process be made ready and for an OS reschedule after sending a USR signal, so allowing the target process to handle the signal 'immediately'?

Comment: @stark, he cannot, if he sents a signal to himself, there's no observable delay from inside the process involved, as the signal handler will be called upon returning of the `kill()` syscall.  Of course he will take two different timestamps, but the time difference has a lot of kernel time involved.

Comment: @Luis I assume the signal is sent from a different process.

Comment: @stark, anyway, the list of events is the same.  The issuing of the signal from a different process can produce longer times, if the receiving process happens to be swapped out.  Think that you are timing wall clock timestamps.... not cpu time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Theoretically, let's say process A is running and it sent a signal to process B, When process B starts running it might never run in kernel mode those never see the signal and handle it.

Linux is a [preemptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking) operating system. This means that the kernel gives every process a [time slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice) and the CPU will receive a hardware [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) in regular time intervals, which will return it to kernel-mode, so that the kernel can, for example, give a time slice to a different process.

Therefore, the situation you describe (that a process will run forever in user-mode and never reach kernel-mode) will never occur in a preemptive multitasking operating system such as Linux.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, let's say the time slice ended so we entered kernel-mode and decided to run another process then we aren't returning to the original process to check if there are any signals...

Comment: @Dan: Even if another process is scheduled first, the original process will eventually be rescheduled. When that happens, the signal will be handled.

Comment: Well, I would suggest that it is difficult to find much accuracy in this answer:(

Comment: 'This means that the kernel gives every process a time slice' no, that is not correct.  Preemptive multitaskers do not need to 'time slice' anything if the number of ready threads is not greater than the number of cores.

Comment: 'process will run forever in user-mode and never reach kernel-mode) will never occur in a preemptive multitasking operating system' not correct, in general.

Answer (score 1):

> But that doesn't make sense to me, why?

Signals **must be handled in user mode and in the process context of the signalled process**, so they cannot be processed while the process is issuing a system call (or executing another process's threads).  In addition, due to the atomicity of many of these system calls, there's only chance to interrupt the system call to process the signal, or to handle them after the system call is finished.  You are only warranteed that the signal handler will be executed **before** any other process' user code, but they are not instantaneous (well, they are, but only from the point of view of the process, not from the system)

But the most important reason is the first one:  The *return from kernel mode* interface has special code to execute signal handlers associated to a signal before returning from the system call, but as this has to be executed in user mode, there's no other efficient way to switch the context, execute the user code, and return back to the kernel code being executed.  This could open also a bunch of security issues (a process forcing the kernel to schedule more than permitted the process because it has a lot of signal handlers attached)  This code has to distinguish if the kernel mode executed was a synchrounous call (some system call executed by the process) or some asynchronous event (a hardware interrupt) because the user code must simulate a return from a system call (with a returning value and/or `errno` setting) or a return from interrupt (which must preserve all registers and flags prior to the interrupt)  This code is normally pushed by tweaking the user stack (this in kernel mode) before swtiching to user mode and returning.

There's one special scenario in which a process is interrupted by a hardware interrupt (e.g. a clock tick) interrupts user mode executing code, and a pending signal is detected.  Then, before returning back to user code, a special code sequence is needed and installed in the user process' stack, to execute the signal handler and issue interrupt-return code (this meaning a special machine code sequence to execute the signal handler and then restore completely the cpu status before the system returns to what the user process was doing before the clock tick) in order to cope with the case that the interrupt came in the middle of some sensible task (an asynchronous interrupt can come at any point in time, between any user code machine instructions)

Last, imagine a process that, due to system load has been swapped out to disk and has no image available to run code (even the signal handler code has been swapped out)  How can you execute the signal handler if no data structures or code of the process are ready to run?

The way the kernel makes the user code to execute the signal handler is to tweak the process stack to force (on return from syscal/interrupt) a call to the signal handler and then restore the full cpu state (as it is done from a hardware interrupt) so the process can continue executing machine instructions as if nothing had happened in between.  This is done **after** the kernel-mode/user-mode switch has been done, so the only workable point to do it is just tweaking the stack.  Linux, just like BSD or all other unix flavours, install this code in the process image, in order for it to be available in every user mode process.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, the situation you describe (that a process will run forever
> in user-mode and never reach kernel-mode) will never occur in a
> preemptive multitasking operating system such as Linux.

Example of when this statement is incorrect :
When we run rt-thread on a particular cpu in linux, there will be no pre-emption, so in that case there will be trouble, but ofcourse there will be many more issues in that situation I believe.